# Customize fieldset output from form collection in ZF2

Tags: zend-framework2, formcollection, zend-form2

I have correctly set up a form in ZF2, which includes several elements and a collection containing a fieldset that can be duplicated by the user. All works fine, but I need more control on how the fieldset renders, ie. I need to add other things between some elements in the fieldset, rather than just output them one after another.

I'm not expert in ZF2, but from research I seem to understand that you can declare a custom fieldsetHelper in the formCollection, however:

1. I can't manage to do so; I tried to extend the FormCollection class, and adding `protected $fieldsetHelper = 'myFieldsetHelper';`, which is also declared in the module config, but I get:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function myFieldsetHelper()

2. I'm familiar with extending FormRow helper, but I don't know how the fieldset helper should be written (I only need to add my extra stuff between some elements), and can't find any example on the web.

Any help, please?

Answer (score 1):

You can use other view helpers to customize the forms layout in your view script such as FormLabel, FormText, etc.

Please see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35641597/zend-form-rendering-and-decorators-use-correctly-with-bootstrap/35661749#35661749)

EDIT

You can also loop through all the collection elements in your view script and render separately.

```
<?php
foreach ($this->form->get('collection') as $fieldset) {
    echo $this->formText($fieldset->get('elementName'));
}
?>
```

Comment: But we are talking about a collection element, so in the view I only have `$this->formCollection($this->form->get('myCollection'))`, which renders the fieldsets and template to duplicate them. I could customize the single helpers so that also the elements in the collection would be rendered accordingly, but what I need to do is to add something in between the single elements of the fieldset, not just edit them.